# Overlay a Video on a Video / Merge 2 Videos to one

Tags: python, c#, video, youtube, mp4

Hey i searching for a coding solution to merge two videos to one.
I want a animated overlay over my videos.
I know its possible to do this with some softwareproducts.
But i want my own coded solution to automate it for all my videos.

What libary can i use for this. The language doesnt really matter but i prefer python or c#.
If someone know an existing solution on github or can share his code would be much better and save me work.

Here you can see an example at this video:

The Like and Subscribe animation start at 22 Secounds:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SA7uXNeVRjs

Edit:
I found now this script but and created a bash from it:

I found now this script with ffmpeg and created a bash from it:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex ^
"[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0] ^
movie=overlay.mp4:s=dv+da[overv][overa] ^
[overv]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+22/TB[v1] ^
[v0][v1]overlay=-600:0:eof_action=pass[out1] ^
[overa]adelay=22000|22000,volume=0.5[a1] ^
[0:a:0][0:a:1][a1]amix=inputs=3:duration=longest:dropout_transition=0:weights=3 3 1[outa]" ^
-map "[out1]" -map "[outa]" output.mp4
```

But if i try to execute it i get back this message:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0] movie=overlay.mp4:s=dv+da[overv][overa] [overv]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+22/TB[v1] [v0][v1]overlay=-600:0:eof_action=pass[out1] [overa]adelay=22000  | 22000,volume=0.5[a1] [0:a:0][0:a:1][a1]amix=inputs=3:duration=longest:dropout_transition=0:weights=3 3 1[outa]" ^
'22000' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Does anyone have an idea why it write this 22000|22000 as 22000  | 22000 in executen or what i need to do to get this script running?

Comment: There is a library called moviepy that is used to automate video editing. [link](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) to documentation.

Comment: The best tool is probably 'ffmpeg'. It's written in C but there is a python interface name "ffmpeg". You can install it with pip.
The python interface does not have documentation but the genuine package has a lot.

Comment: @Jimpsoni ok moviepy sounds good i will have a look at it.

Comment: @user3435121 hmm ok i have allready done alot with ffmpeg but is it possible to do what i need with ffmpeg? Because i didnt found a way to do this with ffmpeg.

Comment: The LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK contains classes that support this functionality. (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). There's a C# example in [this forum post](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/m34516-#post34516) (3rd post in the thread). The example uses an old version of the SDK, but the latest version still contains identical classes, so no code changes are necessary. If you'd like to try it, there's a [free evaluation of LEADTOOLS Multimedia here.](https://leadtools.com/downloads)